# How do I change the Data Type of a Column on TSQL? Specifically when the Data Type is VARCHAR to a INT?

Tags: t-sql

I have a table, it has three columns, school_name, school_number, total_Enrollments. However, total_Enrollments was loaded as a VARCHAR column Data Type. Because of this the column has extra spaces and characters.

Scenario: School A has 621 enrollments but the field was loaded with an extra blank space to 631_, the underscore represents the blank field, when I try Summing this up, it will not because it is a VARCHAR so I cast it as INT in order to sum it up (discloser: I was not the one that designed this table this way, the field should have been numeric or INT from the get-go) but it fails.

Solution: I cannot rebuild this table, is there a way through T-SQL that I can change the data type and remove weird characters and extra spaces so that I may use a SUM function to tally the column?

[image]

Comment: Numbers don't contain line breaks. You need clean data before you can change the data type.

Comment: There's the function try_cast https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 that tries to cast a varchar and if it fails won't return an error but a null value. You could of course trim https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 the column before the try_cast in order to remove the spaces in front or the end first.

Comment: Is your column supposed to only contain `int` data, or could it contain `numeric` data too? A value like `'1.0'`, for example, can't be directly converted to an `int`.

Comment: Note that [`trim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) has an optional syntax to remove characters in a specific set, e.g. `declare @WhiteSpace as VarChar(10) = Char( 9 ) + Char( 10 ) + Char( 13 ) + Char( 32 ); ... Trim( @WhiteSpace from MyColumn ) ...` to remove tabs, line feeds, carriage returns and spaces.

Comment: Add a new nullable int column. Populate it with the result of `try_cast`. Then, you can choose what to do with the values that failed - fix or drop. When ready, drop the old column and rename the new old to old column name. Note: be careful about things that might depend on the old column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** If you can asure that your required number is on the very left side of the string and you have multiple non-numeric character you can use this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #source;
CREATE TABLE #source(total_Enrollments VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO #source VALUES ('101'), ('102_'), ('103 ');
INSERT INTO #source VALUES ('200' + CHAR(9)), ('201' + CHAR(10)), ('202' + CHAR(13));
INSERT INTO #source VALUES (CHAR(9) + '300'), (CHAR(10) + '301'), (CHAR(13) + '303');

SELECT
    total_Enrollments =
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', total_Enrollments) = 0
         THEN CAST(total_Enrollments AS INT)
         ELSE CAST(LEFT(total_Enrollments, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', total_Enrollments ) - 1) AS INT) END
  , pos  = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', total_Enrollments)
  , orig = total_Enrollments
FROM #source
```

**PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%')** use RegEx where **%[^0-9]%** find the first position of any character that is NOT (expressed by ^) in the range between 0 and 9. Unfortunately the **REPLACE**-Function can't handle RegEx to replace non-numeric character at multiple positions.

**2)** If you have to handle CHAR(0) you can do this by replacing it with the **REPLACE**-Function, below done this in an sub-select.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #source;
CREATE TABLE #source(total_Enrollments VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO #source VALUES (CHAR(0) + '400' + CHAR(9));

SELECT
    total_Enrollments =
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', total_Enrollments) = 0
         THEN CAST(total_Enrollments AS INT)
         ELSE CAST(LEFT(total_Enrollments, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', total_Enrollments ) - 1) AS INT) END
  , pos  = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', total_Enrollments)
  , orig = total_Enrollments
FROM (SELECT total_Enrollments = REPLACE(total_Enrollments , CHAR(0), '') FROM #source) AS sub
```

Please note that REPLACE will find and replace CHAR(10) only if it occures at the beginning of the string. If it occures in any other position you have to use an other collation

> SELECT total_Enrollments = REPLACE(total_Enrollments **COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS**, CHAR(0), '')
> FROM #source

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for 1, teaching me something new, and 2 for absolutely fixing that column in my table. This worked perfectly and I wish I could donate money to you for your efforts to take the time to assist a complete stranger, just know you just saved us from a pretty big delay and I just cannot thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

You must try updating the table

```
UPDATE <your_table>
SET total_Enrollments = REPLACE(total_Enrollments , CHAR(0), '')
WHERE CHARINDEX(CHAR(0), total_Enrollments ) > 0;
```

But then you'll also need to fix whatever is putting this bad data into the table

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(total_Enrollments , CHAR(0), ''))
FROM <your_table>;
```